Unable to use own project on Google SSR API
I am testing the Google Search Researcher Result API and here is what I get when I'm trying to access the API in the OA Playground :
{
  "error": {
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED", 
    "message": "User is not allowed to use project *******.", 
    "code": 403
  }
}

I am using the right app ID for my project and have been carefully following the "tutorial" here : https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/13965946
How can I get past this ? thanks
